# Hard drives goes missing until reboot - what can be the cause?

Tags: hard-disk, raid, mdadm

I am struggling here. My end goal is assembling a RAID-6 array on my PC, but time and again, the assemble doesn't complete (and `cat /proc/mdstat` shows that one drive dropped away). This now happened with two separate drives.

The issue is - I did various tests (rebooting Ubuntu, even going into Windows and formatting (not quick format) the drives/partitions there, and no issues were picked up with the drives).

I suspect it's an issue on my Ubuntu installation but don't know where to start looking in log files etc.

Some output below (11 drives -boot + 10 x 1TB drives)

```
erwin@erwin-ubuntu:~$ sudo smartctl -i --scan
/dev/sda -d scsi # /dev/sda, SCSI device
/dev/sdb -d scsi # /dev/sdb, SCSI device
/dev/sdc -d scsi # /dev/sdc, SCSI device
/dev/sdd -d scsi # /dev/sdd, SCSI device
/dev/sde -d scsi # /dev/sde, SCSI device
/dev/sdf -d scsi # /dev/sdf, SCSI device
/dev/sdg -d scsi # /dev/sdg, SCSI device
/dev/sdh -d scsi # /dev/sdh, SCSI device
/dev/sdi -d scsi # /dev/sdi, SCSI device
/dev/sdj -d scsi # /dev/sdj, SCSI device
/dev/sdk -d scsi # /dev/sdk, SCSI device
/dev/sdl -d scsi # /dev/sdl, SCSI device
```

The issue is `sdd` and `sdk` (although they were available on boot), once I tried assembling on MDADM, after a few hours, a drive just drops out, and is no longer reported as available by either `gparted` or `fdisk`, etc.

```
erwin@erwin-ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk /dev/sdd
fdisk: unable to read /dev/sdd: Input/output error
```

Capture of a working drive

```
erwin@erwin-ubuntu:~$ sudo smartctl -i /dev/sdb
smartctl 5.41 2011-06-09 r3365 [i686-linux-3.0.0-14-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-11 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Barracuda 7200.11
Device Model:     ST31000340AS
Serial Number:    9QJ0MD9F
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 00cca6f07
Firmware Version: SD15
User Capacity:    1,000,203,804,160 bytes [1.00 TB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   8
ATA Standard is:  ATA-8-ACS revision 4
Local Time is:    Sat Dec 17 10:59:13 2011 SAST
```

Capture of the two problematic drives:

```
erwin@erwin-ubuntu:~$ sudo smartctl -i /dev/sdd
smartctl 5.41 2011-06-09 r3365 [i686-linux-3.0.0-14-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-11 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

Vendor:               /6:0:0:0
Product:              
User Capacity:        600,332,565,813,390,450 bytes [600 PB]
Logical block size:   774843950 bytes
scsiModePageOffset: response length too short, resp_len=47 offset=50 bd_len=46
>> Terminate command early due to bad response to IEC mode page
A mandatory SMART command failed: exiting. To continue, add one or more '-T permissive' options.


erwin@erwin-ubuntu:~$ sudo smartctl -i /dev/sdh
smartctl 5.41 2011-06-09 r3365 [i686-linux-3.0.0-14-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-11 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

Vendor:               /11:0:0:
Product:              0
User Capacity:        600,332,565,813,390,450 bytes [600 PB]
Logical block size:   774843950 bytes
scsiModePageOffset: response length too short, resp_len=47 offset=50 bd_len=46
>> Terminate command early due to bad response to IEC mode page
A mandatory SMART command failed: exiting. To continue, add one or more '-T permissive' options.
```

A command recommended on another forum, `lsscsi`:

```
erwin@erwin-ubuntu:~$ lsscsi
[0:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      ST3500630AS      3.AA  /dev/sda
[2:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      ST31000340AS     SD15  /dev/sdb
[3:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      ST31000528AS     CC38  /dev/sdc
[6:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      ST31000340AS     SD15  /dev/sdd
[7:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      ST31000528AS     CC36  /dev/sde
[8:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      ST31000340AS     SD15  /dev/sdf
[10:0:0:0]   disk    ATA      ST31000340AS     SD15  /dev/sdg
[11:0:0:0]   disk    ATA      ST31000340AS     SD15  /dev/sdh
[12:0:0:0]   disk    ATA      ST31000340AS     SD15  /dev/sdi
[13:0:0:0]   disk    ATA      ST31000340AS     SD15  /dev/sdj
[14:0:0:0]   disk    ATA      ST31000340AS     SD15  /dev/sdk
[15:0:0:0]   disk    ATA      ST31000340AS     SD15  /dev/sdl
```

Will post/edit details after reboot shortly..

Comment: The clues will be in `/var/log/kern.log`.

Comment: By the way, you don't need a separate boot drive if you are using grub2, which Ubuntu switched to in 9.10.